# How to use potentiometer data from slave to master Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I'm trying to make a game where i can use one Arduino as a controller (the controller is a potentiometer) and the other Arduino sending the signals to the computer. Im trying to figure out communication with two Arduino's so i would like to use two instead of one although using one would be logical and easier. Ive tried looking into I2C but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why are you using 2 Arduinos? You could do all of this in just one Arduino.

Comment: Please also improve the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the potentiometer. Add a Wire [request service function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnRequest) and that makes the Slave:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const uint8_t controllerAddress = 8;
const int controllerPin = A0;
volatile int controllerValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(controllerAddress);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); 
}

void loop() {
  int value = analogRead(controllerPin);
  noInterrupts(); 
    controllerValue = value;  
  interrupts();
}

void requestEvent() {
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*) &controllerValue, sizeof(controllerValue)); 
}
```

This is minor update of the [Arduino Wire Master Reader](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader) tutorial. The sketch for the Master is left as an exercise.

Cheers!

Comment: I would assign 'A0' to controllerPin instead of '0', to avoid any confusing with digital pins: const int controllerPin = A0;

Comment: Nice catch. I will fix that.